# determining the pointwise limit of a function

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

> Consider $f_n : [0, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
>   $$f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l} n^3 x^2, & 0 < x < 1/n; \\
> n^3\left(x - \frac 2 n\right)^2, & 1/n \le x < 2/n; \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.$$
>   Determine the pointwise limit $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.

By drawing out the function for different values of n I can tell the pointwise limit is going to be $n$ but how do I show this? would I have to use the supremum norm?

Comment: The pointwise limit is not $n$ (and that really doesn't make any sense: $n$ is exactly the quantity that's changing); how did you conclude that?

Comment: For all $x \in [0,2]$, there exists some $n$ such that $x$ satisfies $\mbox{otherwise}$. So the pointwise limit is $0$.

Comment: for $n=1$ I get that the maximum point is $1$ and similarly for $n=2$ and $n=3$

Comment: The maximum of each $f_n$ doesn't tell you anything about what the pointwise limit is.

Comment: @T.Bongers could you explain what pointwise limit is?

Comment: See my answer. ${}$

Comment: @smith Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence In particular, the pointwise limit is a function, not a value.

Answer (score 10):

The pointwise limit is not $n$, for several reasons. The simplest of these is that $n$ is exactly the quantity that is changing, not something fixed - it makes absolutely no sense to write something along the lines of

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = n$$

---

As far as a hint for the correct answer: If $x = 0.0001$, then $f_n(x)$ satisfies condition "otherwise" as soon as $n = 20,001$. Generalize this.

Comment: this makes sense, but when it says pointwise limit what am I looking for exactly?

Comment: The pointwise limit is $f(x)$. For each $x$, $f_n(x)$ forms a sequence, and you take the limit of that sequence.

Comment: im still slightly confused, so I need to find the sequence $f(x)$ and once I find this sequence I take the limit as $n \to \infty$

Comment: @smith $f(x)$ is a real number, not a sequence. $f$ is a real-valued function. $f_1(x), f_2(x), \ldots$ is a sequence of real numbers that may have a limit (the question implies it does).

Comment: @djechlin ohhh this makes sense! so I take the limit of the sequence $f_n(x)$. how would I take the limit considering this is a piecewise function?

Comment: is the limit simply $0$

Comment: @smith this is the part you have to figure out...

Comment: okay I'm pretty certain as the limit goes to infinity we get $0$, but how would I explain this? I noticed this because as n goes to infinity our constraints all become $0$

Comment: @smith can you write a proof?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37776/discussion-between-smith-and-djechlin).

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N:\ f_n(0) = 0,$$
and if $x\in(0,2]:\ x>2/n$ for $n$ large enough and $f_n(x) = \cdots$

Answer (score 2):

Firstly observe that $$\left(0,\frac1n\right)\to \emptyset$$ as $n\to+\infty$ (where $\emptyset$ denotes the empty set), so that the first part of the function disappears in the limit. Similarly, for the second part $$\left[\frac1n, \frac2n\right)\to \emptyset$$ as $n\to+\infty$. So, there is not really much left.

Comment: Haven't seen the notation "goes to the empty set." Closed sets that go to the empty set would be a different story.